# SDN 4 missing relationships in the graph

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

When I store my Neo4j nodes to the Neo4j graph, only nodes are stored (no relationships). Does anyone can point me to right direction what i am missing there?

here are my nodes

```
@NodeEntity public class Game extends AbstractEntity{

     public Long        timestamp;
     public double  total_pot_size;

     public int     flop;
     public int     turn;
     public int     river;

     @Relationship(type = "ROUND")
     public Set<Round> rounds;

     @Relationship(type = "OUTCOME")
     public Set<Outcome> outcomes;


     public Game() {
         super();
     }

     public void add(Outcome outcome) {
         if (outcomes == null) {
            outcomes = new HashSet<Outcome>();
         }
         outcomes.add(outcome);
     }

     public void add(Round round) {
         if (rounds == null) {
             rounds = new HashSet<Round>();
         }
        rounds.add(round);
     }
 }
```

and

```
@NodeEntity public class Player extends AbstractEntity {

    public String   name;
    public String   platform;

    @Relationship(type = "PARTICIPATION", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    public Set<Participation> involved_games;

    @Relationship(type = "OWNS")
    public Set<Statistics> statistics;

    public Player() {
        super();
    }

    public void participate(Participation involved_game) {
        if (involved_games == null) {
            involved_games  = new HashSet<Participation>();
        }
        involved_games.add(involved_game);
    }

    public void add(Statistics stat) {
        if (statistics == null) {
            statistics  = new HashSet<>();
        }
        statistics.add(stat);
    }
}
```

here is the code i use to store my data.

```
    // create or get a new game in database
    Game    game    = gameRepo.save( DataUtil.createGame(gi) );

    // get the player involved to the game
    List<Player> players    = gi.getPlayers();
    // for each player involved to the game...
    for (Player player : players) {
        org.quazar.data.domain.Player p = store(player);
        // relationship participation
        p.participate(DataUtil.createParticipation(p, game, player));
        // set the outcome of the players
        game.add(DataUtil.createOutcome(game, p, gi, player));
        playerRepo.save(p);
    }

    gameRepo.save( game );
```

the store(player) method saves or retrieve (if not new) a player, which works properly. DataUtil.createParticipation and DataUtil.createOutcome methods creates new relationships (g.e. new Outcome()) and set the properties.

When running my application i do not get any exceptions, but in the graph i miss my relationships.

I did not listed all the nodes (e.g. Statistics) because right now i do not use them in my model, could that cause the problem?

Here are some relationships:

```
@RelationshipEntity(type = "PARTICIPATION")
public class Participation extends AbstractEntity {

    @StartNode
    public Player   player;

    @EndNode
    public Game     game;

    @Property
    public double   bankroll;

    @Property
    public int      holecards;
    @Property
    public byte     position;

    public Participation () {
        super();
    }

}
```

and

```
@RelationshipEntity(type = "OUTCOME")
public class Outcome extends AbstractEntity {

    @StartNode
    public Game     game;

    @EndNode
    public Player   player;

    @Property
    public String   type;

    @Property
    public String   round;

    @Property
    public double   pot_size;
    @Property
    public double   ante;

    @Property
    public int      holecards;
    @Property
    public String   bestHand;
    @Property
    public int      bestHandrank;

    public Outcome() {
        super();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Luanne thanks for editing

Comment: Does someone has any hints i can look  for?

Comment: How do you create the Participation and Outcome entity? Sharing a test case for example would help, hard to tell from the code what is going wrong. You use DataUtil.createParticipation for example, but we don't know what that code looks like

Comment: @Luanne thanks again. I edited the question again. I've tried to avoid spam with to much code, but anyone wants more specific code i can share it then.

Comment: Does createParticipation set both the player and the game and maintain correct references from the Player class? Can you share your project somewhere?

Comment: Yes both player and game are set correctly and maintain the correct references. I don't won't to share my hole project, but i will see if i can find time to build an example project, next time.

Comment: Okay, sorry, can't guess what's going wrong. Please try to share a full test.